# Simulate mouse movement with .click() or .move_to_element() Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, bots

I am working on a Selenium bot project and I've noticed that websites can easily detect that a bot is going through a website buy getting the X and Y of a cursor, because driver.click() function jumps directly to the location of the element. Is there any way that I can simulate mouse movement to prevent detection.

```
findtop = driver.find_element_by_class_name('topbutton').click()
time.sleep(3)
findbottom = driver.find_element_by_class_name('bottomButton').click()
```

Here's what I get in the console:

```
X:26 Y: 19
X:1006 Y: 707
```

I even tried:

```
findtop = driver.find_element_by_class_name('topbutton').click()
time.sleep(3)
findbottom = driver.find_element_by_class_name('bottomButton')

webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(findtop).perform()

findbottom = driver.find_element_by_class_name('bottomButton')
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(findbottom).perform()
```

Same result.

Comment: What website are you using it on?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan I wanna use it on Linkedin, but I am trying to prevent detection and testing this in my own environment